# How to place an image over a button or a panel in octave?

Tags: octave

I want to place an image over a button or a panel in octave, tried many ways but couldn't get it. I want to display something like this:

[image]

I tried this piece of code, but all I get is a blank button:

```
f = figure ("toolbar", "none");
% create empty toolbar
t = uitoolbar (f);
% create a 19x19x3 black square
img=imread('12.jpg');
% add pushtool button to toolbar
b = uicontrol('style','pushbutton',...
            'units','pixels',...
            'position',[10, 20, 10, 20],...
            'cdata', uint64(img))
```

Comment: Hi, it looks like you are new in here, please follow the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) format when asking a question, from there we will help you.

Comment: Yes, @Rich Thank You

Comment: This code doesn't seem to work( error: invalid value for array property "cdata" ). Also, I'd replace with `img = zeros([19,19,3]);` here to make it directly copy / pasteable for users trying to help. Having said that, I'm still not clear what you're trying to do (or what that image is meant to be showing). Are you trying to place images to the left and right of an existing button?

Comment: also, you're not using a panel, you're using a "toolbar" there. That's an entirely different thing (a toolbar is the menu-like strip that appears immediately below the "File, View, Edit" menu, which can hold togglebuttons etc).

Comment: ok, I just realised your code is from the "uipushtool" documentation example from octave. Yeah you cannot add a uicontrol on a uitoolbar. You can only add compatible items. Conversely (and more relevant to you), you are probably trying to add a uicontrol on a uipanel instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you're after, but you can create an image and assign it a callback function directly. No need to make it a uicontrol pushbutton. You can do this whether the image is by itself or embedded in a uipanel, etc. E.g.

```
Fig = figure(1);
MyPanel = uipanel( 'units'   , 'normalized', 
                   'position', [0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 0.6], 
                   'title'   , 'My Panel' );

% Draw smiley
Sm = cat(3, ones(11,11), ones(11,11), zeros(11,11) ); % Draw background
Sm(3, 3, 3) = 1; Sm(3, 9, 3) = 1; Sm(9, 3:9, 3) = 1;  % Draw face

Ax = axes( MyPanel, 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 0.6] );

function Im_callback( Handl, Evnt )
  set( Handl, 'cdata', double( ~get( Handl, 'cdata' ) ) );
end

Im = imagesc( Ax, Sm, 'buttondownfcn', @Im_callback );
axis off;
```

You get this picture. Click on the 'smiley face' to see what happens* :)

[image]

---

<sub>* obviously, I mean when you run this in octave, not here!</sub>